A story about a boy with a fever who falls in the creek and is saved by an angel and grows up to be Hitler
I read this story years ago in elementary school and it has stuck with me ever since. I'm sure it was in a compilation book.
The premise is a sick little boy with a fever who is delirious and wanders out in the night and falls into a creek or river and almost drowns,then a beautiful angel saves him and takes him back home.
The last line always stuck with me because it entails the entire twist of the story
The boy asks who the angel is and she replies

"I am the one who put the serpent into the garden Adolf but I was only following orders"


Clearly the Mercedes was sorely missing which recognizes dangers before they emerge.

Sounds similar to the concept of The Mysterious Stranger by Mark Twain

Angelica by Jane Yolen. I read it in the anthology 100 Great Fantasy Short Short Stories.
The ending you remember is:

She lifted him up and cradled him in her arms. She sang him a lullaby in a language he did not know. "I told you in the beginning who I am," she murmured to the sleeping boy. "I am Pistias Sophia, angel of wisdom and faith. The one who put the serpent into the garden, little Adolf. But I was only following orders."
Her wings unfurled behind her. She pumped them once, twice, and then the great wind they commanded lifted her into the air. She flew without a sound to the Hitler house and left the boy sleeping, feverless, in his bed.

